# Kotlin - How do i set a sharedpreference code so that i open the closed app, it opens the last Activity, where i left it

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences

I made two activities in my application, I want the app to be opened where I left off. In other words, not the default activity but the activity where I was when I last exited the app.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code so others can see what you've already tried.  You will also have a better experience here if you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Start by saving to `SharedPreferences` the identification of the activity that is been destroyed and start it on app launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a SplashActivity, where your app start, that will start other activities.

In this SplashActivity, you can set a var lastActivity, that will be a code to keep in which activity you were last time.
You get it with SharedPreference, and then go to the activity.

i.e :

```
String lastActivity = SharedPreference.getString(...) // I don't really remember the syntax
if (lastActivity == "HelloWorldActivity")
    startActivity(HelloWorldActivity.getStartIntent(context))
else if (lastActivity == "GoodByeActivity")
    startActivity(GoodByeActivity.getStartIntent(context))
```

Then, do NOT forget to edit your SharedPreference value EACH TIME you change activity.

I don't know if this is a good practice, but feel free to test this and give your think.

EDIT

First, you need to understand how is Shared Preference File. I think it looks like this :

```
"app_name"="Your app name"
"last_activity"="Your last activity"
"user_age"="23"
```

This could be the first activity you launch :

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var lastActivity = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate()

        /*
            Here, we will get the SharedPreferencesFile.
            Then, we get the value linked to the key TAG_LAST_ACTIVITY (set in companion object)
        */
        val sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_preference_file_name), 0)
        lastActivity = sharedPref.getString(TAG_LAST_ACTIVITY, "")

        var activityToStart : AppCompatActivity? = null
        if (lastActivity.isBlank())
             activityToStart = YourActivityToStartAtFirstLaunch.getStartIntent(this)
        else if (lastActivity.equals(TAG_ACTIVITY_ONE))
             activityToStart = ActivityOne.getStartIntent(this)
        else if (lastActivity.equals(TAG_ACTIVITY_TWO))
             activityToStart = ActivityTwo.getStartIntent(this)
        else if
             ... // Use as many as else if you need, but think about the "when" condition, it is better !

        startActivity(activityToStart)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG_LAST_ACTIVITY = "last_activity"
        private const val TAG_ACTIVITY_ONE = "activity_one"
        private const val TAG_ACTIVITY_TWO = "activity_two"
    }
}
```

And this could be your ActivityOne, for example :

```
class ActivityOne : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate()

        /*
            Here, we will modify the variable LAST_ACTIVITY in the shared preferences file by setting it to "activity_one".
            So, if the user quit this app now, you will know at next launch in which activity he stopped.
            I think it is a better practice to set this in the onPause() or onStopped() method. Think about it ! ;)
        */
        val sharedPrefEditor = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_preference_file_name, 0)).edit()
        sharedPrefEditor.putString(TAG_LAST_ACTIVITY, TAG_ACTIVITY_ONE)
        sharedPrefEditor.apply()
    }

    companion object {
        fun getStartIntent(context : Context) : Intent = Intent(context, ActivityOne()::class.java)

        private const val TAG_ACTIVITY_ONE = "activity_one"
        private const val TAG_LAST_ACTIVITY = "last_activity"
    }    
}
```

Do not forget to put your shared preference file name in your values/strings.xml file :

```
<string name="shared_preference_file_name">com.example.yourappname.sharedpref"</string>
```

Comment: i don't know where do i add this code? i'm a complete noob! :'(,

Comment: @Aboodi I have edited my answer. Check it out, and feel free to ask for more explanations.